# Make Container.height = Right_Column.height

Tags: jquery, css

it's simple as that :)

The column on my right changes dynamically, and since the height of the left column is set to 100%, I thought it would be good to dynamically modify the height of the container depending on what the height of the Right_Column is. Any tips? Thanks :)

Comment: See: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: "The container" of what, exactly?

Comment: I did a little jsfiddle to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/wXyDq/ Neither the container or 'left' stretch down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, if I understand the question correctly

```
var h = $('#left').height();
$('#right').css('height', h + 'px');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/KrhAP/2/

Is that what you wanted?

**EDIT**

As per your comment,

just add `overflow:hidden;` to

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and change your jQuery to be this, placing it inside the `click()`

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#right").html("adsd<BR>adsd<BR>adsd<BR>adsd<BR>adsd<BR>adsd<BR>adsd<BR>adsd<BR>adsd<BR>adsd<BR>adsd<BR>adsd<BR>adsd<BR>");

  var h = $('#right').height();
  $('#left').css('height', h + 'px');

});
```

NB: I also had to switch the `#right` and `#left` from my original after you changed the fiddle.

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/wXyDq/2/

Comment: Hello, I tried that and it didn't work so I made a little js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/wXyDq/ Notice that both divs are inside a container yet that container doesn't stretch down at all - neither does 'left' and it's height is set to 100%.

Comment: With the combination of the script at the beggining, this works like a charm :) However, I'm having trouble updating the height of the main column when I unhide a div which makes it larger, even after adding $('#right').css('height', h + 'px'); at the end of my function - do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function({
    var x = $('#primary').height();
    $('#sidebar').css('height', x);
});
```

This works for me, hope it helps.